# Log in user using Wordpress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, wordpress-rest-api, nonce

I am having problems authenticating a user after logging in using a custom endpoint using the WordPress REST API.

I'm aware that this is not the perfect approach but I am just trying to make a few custom routes so that I can prototype a mobile app. I have searched countless forums and I have looked at a number of other answers but I can't seem to find out what the problem is in my code.

Code to create a User account

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_test_register_user_routes' );
function my_test_register_user_routes() {
    
    register_rest_route( APP_NAMESPACE, '/user', [
        'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
        'callback' => 'my_test_create_user',
    ] );
}

function my_test_create_user($request) 
{   
    //create user and get ID
    $new_user = [];
    $new_user['username'] = $request['username'];
    $new_user['email'] = $request['email'];
    $new_user['password'] = $request['password'];

    $user = wp_insert_user( [
        'user_login' => $new_user['username'],
        'user_email' => $new_user['email'],
        'user_pass' => $new_user['password']
    ] );

    if( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        return rest_ensure_response( [
            'error' => 1,
            'msg' => $user->get_error_message()
        ] );
    }
        
    return rest_ensure_response( ['User' => 'User created'] );
}
```

Code to log in a user

```
/* 
    ========================AUTHENTICATION ROUTES========================
*/
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_test_register_authentication_routes' );
function my_test_register_authentication_routes() {
    
    register_rest_route( APP_NAMESPACE, '/login', [
        'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
        'callback' => 'my_test_login_user',
    ] );
}

function my_test_login_user($request) 
{   
    $creds = [];
    $creds['user_login'] = $request["user"];
    $creds['user_password'] =  $request["password"];
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false ); 
    
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        return rest_ensure_response( [
            'login' => 0,
            'msg'   => $user->get_error_message()
        ] );
    

    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID,true);
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $current_user = 'Y';
    } else {
        $current_user = 'N';
    }
    
    return rest_ensure_response( [
        'login' => 1,
        'id' => $user->ID,
        'nonce' => $nonce,
        'is_user_logged_in' => $current_user,
        'msg'   => 'You have successfully logged in'
    ] );
}
```

Now all this looks fine, the user is successfully logged in and expected the data is returned.

The code to check if the user is logged in below

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'check_status_route' );
function check_status_route($request)
{
    register_rest_route( APP_NAMESPACE, '/status', [
        'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'check_status',
    ] );
}

function check_status($request)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $status = "Logged In";
    } else {
        $status = "Logged Out";
    }
    
    return rest_ensure_response( ['status' => $status] );
}
```

The `check_status()` function returns the following

```
{
    "code": "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce",
    "message": "Cookie nonce is invalid",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-wp-nonce"` in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @flowermia, I have just tried that and I am now getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

More specifically, I added `Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-WP-Nonce"`

But also it doesn't work when I add the nonce as a query parameter in the URL so I don't think that is the reason for it not working.

Comment: @flowermia I removed that line and it is working again. I can remove the header and send the nonce in the URL and I still get the error message.

Comment: @flowermia, so I had to enable the `mod_headers module`. I did that and now the site is working again but I am still getting the same output. I have tried deleting cookies and retrying a number of times.

Comment: Hi @Courtney I'm trying to do the same as you - I've read all the docs and can't see another way of doing this other than creating your own REST API route as you did - but can you please tell me why this method is "not ideal"? Is it not secure? What are my other options? Thanks

Comment: @SeanH, sorry for just getting back to you. It appears the stackoverflow app is no longer working. So I had to log in to see your response.

I think the general consensus is to use something like JWTs or other API keys. Here is a link that provides some plugin options. 

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/